# How to calculate count and percentage of total for each category using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data set with a column called ratings from 1 to 5. The result should be as follows:

```
Rating  Count  Count %
1         10    6.66%
2         20    13.33%
3         30    20.00%
4         40    26.66%
5         50    33.33%
```

Total Ratings: 150

(1) All percentages should be approximated in 2 decimal places
(2) The result should be in a data frame with column names - Rating, Count & Count%

How to get this result using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Using math and **`apply`** with string formatting:

```
df.Count.div(df.Count.sum()).apply('{0:.2%}'.format)

0     6.67%
1    13.33%
2    20.00%
3    26.67%
4    33.33%
Name: Count, dtype: object
```

Comment: It's not working - 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Count' - also we need to store the results in seperate columns

Comment: any idea about the solution?